# dbclick does not work in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have the following JS code fragment (using Raphael lib) and this double click does not work - does anybody can help me sort out why?

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 600, 500);
var shape=[];
var shapefill=[];
shape[1] = paper.path('m150,150 l40,0 l0,20 l-40,0 l0,-20z');
shapefill[1]=toothsurface[1].attr({fill:'#FF33FF'})
shapefill[1].dbclick(function ()
{
   window.location="http://127.0.0.1:8000/dbclick/";
});
```

note: this works perfectly well with a "shapefill[1].click(...);"

Answer (score 2):

It should be `dblclick`, not `dbclick`

From the [source](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael.js#L45), Raphael.js supports following events - *click dblclick mousedown mousemove mouseout mouseover mouseup touchstart touchmove touchend orientationchange touchcancel gesturestart gesturechange gestureend*

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean [`dblclick`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Events) rather than `dbclick`?